# Streaming events to Big Query - Dataflow - Best way to insert **epoch timestamp** (int) to timestamp column

Tags: python, timestamp, apache-beam, epoch, bq

I am trying to write events in streaming into Big Query table using dataflow apache beam (python) having a problem with timestamp format.

I have an event (json) with **epoch timestamp** (int) values which I want to insert into BIG QUERY table with **timestamp** columns .

What is the best way to do it ?
Can I do it without parsing each event ? can I declare the format of the timestamp received ?

for example :

```
event= {'ts' : 1630494181342 ,'user' : 'anat'}
```

Into table :

```
{ts: timestamp , user: string}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam applies the transformations on all the elements that are passed through the pipeline. So, the defined pipeline steps will convert the epoch time epoch time to datetime format on a per element basis before ingesting it into BigQuery.

The following Apache Beam pipeline code will convert the epoch time in seconds to datetime ie. timestamp

Example code:

```
import apache_beam as beam
 
class GetTimestamp(beam.DoFn):
 def process(self, mytime, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
   yield '{}'.format(timestamp.to_utc_datetime())
 
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
 plant_timestamps = (
     pipeline
     | 'My Time' >> beam.Create([
         {'ts': 1633013727, 'user': 'anant'},
         {'ts': 1590969600, 'user':'samwilliam'},   
     ])
     | 'With timestamps' >> beam.Map(
         lambda mytime: beam.window.TimestampedValue(mytime, mytime['ts']))
     | 'Get timestamp' >> beam.ParDo(GetTimestamp())
     | beam.Map(print)
 )
```